# How can we prevent Stack Overflow veterans from posting low quality answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

Moments ago I came across this question regarding JavaScript: *[How to display array objects using a simple loop and if statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533487/how-to-display-array-objects-using-a-simple-loop-and-if-statements)*. It was instantly answered by a Stack Overflow veteran with 400k+ reputation and soon after accepted.

Not that the question was of any good quality, but neither was the answer. It didn't have almost any attributes of a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). So I decided to contribute my own answer. And I did it in a verbose way. I could have answered more concisely, but my main point was that the OP will not learn any lesson from such an answer and will show up on another day to spam another substandard question. Why can't we have more answers similar to those from [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert?tab=answers), [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=answers) and many others?

I don't expect superior answers from members with low reputation, but I didn't expect experienced veteran huddle a job through either.

Am I right to say that such low-quality answers encourage even more low-quality questions? Is it really [worth that +15 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3742/what-motivates-people-to-answer-questions-in-stack-overflow)?

Comment: It takes a special type of person to write these kinds of detailed, long-form answers. They're called teachers. Not everyone is willing or able to do this. Fortunately, the reputation system tends to reward the best answers over time.

Comment: The answer provided by Barmar was actually a pretty good answer. It fixed the OP's problem and explained the essential details of how the code works. It wasn't perfect, and it's great that you wrote your own answer, but I don't see any problem with high-rep users answering questions with answers like this one.

Comment: @cs95 Yeah, what's with people who call out specific users in a negative light on Meta by linking to their profiles? That doesn't sit too well with me, either.

Comment: @PikachutheParenthesisWizard I agree, of all people who could be criticised, **Barmar** is probably the last of them. He *could* have put more effort into the answer, sure, but I don't think this one is bad, either. I'd also agree that OP's answer is better but it's not an either/or situation here - both are decent answers deserving an upvote. As a side-note - the question is really good, too. Way higher quality than the average even before it was edited. The OP there deserves some appreciation, too.

Comment: As another side-note, the accepted answer was changed. I literally saw it happen after I opened this question and then followed the link - **Barmar**'s question had the green tick which disappeared and reappeared on the other answer.

Comment: @CodyGray So moderate. Starting witch hunts on meta is definitely not ok. I have now flagged the comment as unfriendly.

Comment: evergreen canonical: **[Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773)**, _"The idea of Stack Overflow is rotten. It was excellent when trees were high and traffic was low. It turned bad now; it has become a honeypot for all the "enthusiast programmers" of the world, eager to share their 2 cents faster than you can say the word "close".

You're killing a great resource. Despite all the nice words and proper declarations, it discourages the reuse of the knowledge. And encourages fast on-site answers..."_

Comment: ^^^ ...and just in case if someone wonders how come that things didn't improve in years passed, this is likely because [no effort was made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314348/165773)

Comment: In case anyone is curious, I upvoted your answer myself. And somehow, I still managed to get a "Nice Answer" badge for my answer, as minimal as it is. Maybe some upvoted me because they don't think I deserve this lashing.

Comment: For what it's worth, your answer looks like it would be more appropriate for a [codereview.se] question, as it suggests redesigning data structures and refactoring the code. I generally try to keep my answers close to the OP's design, showing how to fix their specific errors. Doing much more is likely to overwhelm and confuse the readers, IMHO.

Comment: @Barmar I did that on purpose. The message in between the lines says: dropping a few more words of knowledge woudn't hurt anyone.

Comment: @PeterWolf, I understand your feeling, and I definitely see value in your answer, but I also agree with what have already been said by some others: the previously accepted answer was not bad, it was a (presumably) correct answer to a specific question, and that's what Stack Overflow is for - Questions and Answers. Your type of answer *does* fit better on Code Review, and while I still think it's a valuable addition on Stack Overflow (so please go on), it should not be the norm and certainly not decrease the value of other (shorter but still correct) answers. My 2 cents.

Comment: PS: About your statement *"I don't expect superior answers from members with low reputation"*. Why is that? Are low-rep members stupid? Maybe they just haven't been member for a long time. I don't see why a new member cannot post an excellent answer :-)

Comment: @wovano: That's how you read it. Don't put that words in my mouth. I myself am a new member. Check out my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11562188/peter-wolf?tab=answers).

Comment: @Peter, I didn't try to put words in your mouth. I asked what you meant (and indeed stated how I read it, because that could be different than what you intended (which seems to be the case)). And I also said in my previous comment that I *do* value your answers.

Comment: No offense, but I don't think your answer is good. Not due to any technical problems, but because the question isn't stellar and your answer is a deep dive into a very specific but very basic programming problem. It's more of a mentoring/tutoring session, meaning the probability of it ever helping somebody other than OP is rather low. But it has the potential to turn up in unrelated searches and make other content harder to find. That goes against one of the core tenets of SO to create a high quality information repository (although to be fair, SE seems to have abandoned that goal).

Comment: @Cody knowing you, that was probably directed at me to some degree as well, but just to be clear I was making an example of the fact that this isn't a one off thing, nor is it necessarily a bad thing either. Ah well, damage done.

Answer (score 19):

If this is your definition of a bad question and answer, you haven't been around at SO. *At all.*

Let me show you a sample of a random post that just popped up as I type this. Formatting by the OP has been preserved just as in the original question.

Title:

> Answer: Eesha. explain?

Tags: [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)

> ## include
>
> Main(int argc,char**argv)
>
> {
>
> printf(“%s\n”,argv[–argc]);
>
> Return 1;
>
> }
>
> The above program was run with the following command line parameters
>
> Asha usha nisha easha
>
> What was the output?
>
> a. Nisha
>
> b. Unable to run due to compilation error
>
> c. No output,run time error
>
> d. Eesha

*This* is a bad question.

While the one you linked at least has some sort of a problem statement, it has code that could possibly even be a reproducible example ([MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). The answer doesn't look terrible either. It might not be amazing, but it is definitely not something to start a meta thread over.

If you want to fight the flood of crap that constantly washes over SO, you need to pick your fights. And probably lower your quality bar significantly, so meet the substandard requirements of SO in the year 2019.

Comment: A bit disappointed you didn't pick an example that was tagged both C and C++ with Python code in the question ...

Comment: @rene I literally spent 5 seconds looking for a bad question as I typed this answer. That was all it took to find this particular gem. I'm sure there's worse...

Comment: Ah, an answer posted in haste that could have been higher quality then :-)

Comment: Agreed up until "meet the substandard requirements of SO in the year 2019." Garbage questions have been a thing since the very early days of SO. That's not to defend the present situation, or make it sound like I don't think we should do something. Rather, it's just a caution to avoid the "golden age" fallacy. [I've been arguing since *at least* 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174097/is-it-time-to-tighten-up-the-question-quality-filter) that we need to do more to prevent sub-standard "questions" and raise our quality standards.

Comment: @CodyGray Complete trash questions like this one have always been around, true. But questions of the nature "how do I do utterly basic beginner stuff that's explained in chapter 1 of the relevant programming book" used to be closed and down-voted to oblivion. Nowadays they are answered and up-voted. We used to have a requirement that the OP must actually have a clue what they are asking about. The site has gone from "site for professional and enthusiast programmers" to "site where newbies learn, share, & build careers". There _was_ a golden age of sorts, even though it had crap too.

Comment: So the p isn't properly capitalized, big whoopie.  It does take an expert to see through the clutter and understand why the teacher's bad code throws off the student.  Not covered in chapter 1.  When life gives you lemons you make --argc lemonade.

Comment: @HansPassant It should be obvious that you can't access a negative array index. Chapter 2 maybe. No matter, it is a zero effort homework dump.

Answer (score 6):

I will focus on the questions.

> How can we prevent SO veterans from posting low quality answers?

The same way anyone is prevented from posting low quality answers, by downvoting. If contributions are repeatedly received badly, contributors usually cease to contribute that way. This should also apply to veterans.

> Why can't we have more answers similar to those from Eric, Jon and many others?

Because the time, skill and will to do so are obviously rare. We could maybe discuss how to possibly further improve the conditions for those answers. I guess, we do not have to think about rep in this regard. Eric, Jon and many others do it because they love their work here.

> Am I right to say that such low quality answers encourage even more low quality questions?

That's a tricky question. One could argue that a low quality answer that nevertheless answers the question is better than none. And even without low quality answers, the low quality questions could keep coming in. It might not make any difference. Therefore, although it seems like there should be at least some encouragement effect, I would hesitate to quantify it.

My conclusion: Just downvote the really bad, downvote-worthy contributions and move on.

Comment: "*Just downvote the really bad, downvote-worthy contributions and move on.*" (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Which of the two answers to the question linked is the best?

Just asking that is asking an opinion oriented question. Both are great in THEIR OWN WAY.

- The simple, straight forward, solving quick, short answer.
- And the teacher like, deep, long optimizing answer.

You think yours is better? Ok, but maybe I liked the other one more. It's a clash between two very different personalities that made you write this meta question.